# What is a good way to create a dart wrapper for a Javascript API?

Tags: dart, dart2js

suppose I want to create a wrapper for a javascript API such as localStorage that adds some additional functionality like automatically journaling changes and syncing it to a server. Dart already has wrappers for these APIs, what is a good way to create a dart wrapper for my wrapped API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Proxy class for this. There is a good article explaining how this works at http://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/